# If $C_{G}H = G$, then $H \leq Z(G)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I at a point in a proof where I should have this statement be true: If $C_{G}(H) = G$, then $H \leq Z(G)$.

I don't know why, but I am completely drawing a blank as to why this assumption is true.

I know that $C_{G}(H) = \{ g \in G | ghg^{-1}=h$ for all $h \in H \} = G$ and that $Z(G) = \{ g \in G |gx=xg for all x \in G \} = \{ g \in G |gxg^{-1}=x$ for all $x \in G \}$.  So I can see that the centralizer and the center are looking very similar. But I don't know why $H \leq Z(G)$.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to prove first that $H \subset Z(G)$.

If $h \in H$, since $C_G(H) = G$, for all $x\in G$ we have $hx = xh$, that is, $h \in Z(G)$

Comment: Okay, I understand that. How do I show it's a subgroup? Can I not do that?

Comment: For this, we have to assume that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$

Comment: Ooh yea, I was given that H is a normal subgroup of G.

Comment: So, there is nothing last to show, since $H$ already has a group structure with the operation inherited by $G$ and it's the same operation inherit as a subgroup of $Z(G)$.

Comment: But what did the centralizer have to do with any of this? I don't understand how the centralizer equaling G comes into play here.

Comment: Since the centralizer is all $G$, the definition of centralizer states that $hxh^{-1} = x$, so if any $x \in G$ is in the centralizer, $hx = xh$ for every $x$.